# fd leak in parent process for logging in python

Tags: python, logging, memory-leaks

I have server process which spawns a process for each request. Where parent process is leaking fd for logger. Please find example code.

```
from threading import Thread 
from multiprocessing import Process 
from time import sleep 
import logging 
from uuid import uuid4 

class ChildFile(object): 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('test') 
        fh = logging.FileHandler('/tmp/test'+str(uuid4())) 
        fh.setLevel(logging.INFO) 
        self.logger.addHandler(fh) 
        self.fd = open('test2', 'wb') 

    def run(self): 
        self.logger.info('dummy run') 

def child_file_creator(): 
    a = ChildFile() 
    child_process = Process(target=a.run) 
    child_process.start() 
    child_process.join() 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    print 'parent process run' 
    while True: 
        child_file_creator() 
        sleep(10)
```

1) after child process exits.

2) For parent process, still fd remains open. 
one can check out using,

```
cd /proc/23223/fd 

Ideapad-Z570:/proc/23223/fd$ ls -ltr 
total 0 
l-wx------ 1 * * 64 Nov 11 15:10 6 -> /tmp/test62bba7f1-223c-4c17-a483-f6d92ab67222 
l-wx------ 1 * * 64 Nov 11 15:10 5 -> /tmp/test2946cdf6-7e4c-4979-b56a-fd2cc6333398 
l-wx------ 1 * * 64 Nov 11 15:10 4 -> /tmp/test0488579b-10d7-4635-abb0-a31a0ea79eeb 
lr-x------ 1 * * 64 Nov 11 15:10 3 -> /dev/urandom 
lrwx------ 1 * * 64 Nov 11 15:10 2 -> /dev/pts/19 
lrwx------ 1 * * 64 Nov 11 15:10 1 -> /dev/pts/19 
lrwx------ 1 * * 64 Nov 11 15:10 0 -> /dev/pts/19
```

3) while normal file descriptor of open 'test2' is closed. But fd attached to logger is leaking.

How can I close for the same for logger object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialise the logging in the child process, instead of in the parent as you're doing at the moment. Then it shouldn't leak any file descriptors.

Comment: I had the same idea. I was looking if there was cleaner way to do that,i.e initialize everything while object creation. Since, fd with open calls were closed. Thanks.